# When, during authentication, should I ask for an OTP token?

Tags: one-time-password

I was working on implementing an OTP strategy in our login process of a web application when I was asking myself: Should I ask for the OTP token *before* or *after* asking for the username/password?

What I generally see with services I use is, I have to provide the OTP token *after* they've verified my username/password.

I was wondering if this was just due to user experience decisions or if there was a security aspect to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a *security* perspective, it makes sense to ask at the same time -- that way, an attacker doesn't know what they got wrong. With some services (e.g. Google), the OTP has another option to send a text message, so from a *UX* perspective, putting it after the password cuts back on spurious texts.